# CSS bullets layout a little bit to the left

Tags: html, css

How can I push 1, 2 and 3, 4 a little bit further left?

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.n_paragraaf ul {
    line-height: inherit;
    list-style-position: outside !important;
    list-style-type: square !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 5px 1px 1px 5px;
}
.n_paragraaf ul li {

    font-size: 15px !important;
    line-height: inherit;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="n_paragraaf">
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
    <ul>
      <li>l</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code look likes

[image]

Comment: You have one too many closing `</ul>` tags.

Comment: Have you done any research (e.g. google?) into list layouts?

Answer (score 0):

Will this not work for you

```
<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca Cola
        <ol>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply put

```
ul{padding:0;}
```

into your css it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To change how much indentation there is on your list items, you need to change the amount of left margin on the `ul` element, i.e.

```
.n_paragraaf ul {
    margin-left: 10px;  /* change this value! */
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq3wfmj6/1/) and experiment with the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
.n_paragraaf ul {
    line-height: inherit;
    list-style-position: outside !important;
    list-style-type: square !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.n_paragraaf ul li {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    line-height: inherit;
    padding-left: 9px !important;
}
```